# What is the best way to organize daylong testing with Sikuli?

Tags: automated-testing, sikuli, test-infrastructure

Sikuli uses image recognition, so it needs ([from Sikuli quickstart](http://sikulix.com/quickstart/)):

> - Real Screen needed
> - Using Virtual Machines - ...should usually work...
> - Machine not useable in parallel while SikuliX scripts or programs are running

I am using VM and it works fine while it is opened on a real PC via RDP and is not minimized to task pane. This PC even could be locked (we have security restriction on displaying tested application), and Sikuli still works fine.

So until now I have these restrictions in Sikuli usage (sikuli tests are running all day long in a cycle):

1. Separate real PC (see "not useable in parallel while SikuliX running")
2. Several RDP sessions with VM on which each Sikuli test is running are opened on this PC.

Is there any other (especially better) way to organize testing infrastructure for Sikuli tests?

Answer (score 1):

Is this for *web* testing? If so, you can use Kantu. Essentially it is the same as Sikuli, but runs inside the web browser. So you can run many instances at once and in the background. Also, the system can be locked while the test are running.

Comment: RDP like interface is tested, no way to interact with app's objects, just image recognition